# How can I use event listener in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in tutorials I'm seeing something like that :

```
import React from 'react';
function App(){ 
  return(
    <div>
    <h1 onClick={functionName}>Hello React</h1>
  </div>
  );

  
}
export default App;
```

but I think adding "onClick" event to an element is a bad practice , instead we were adding event listener with vanilla JS , but now . I don't know if it is OK or not in reactJS?
is there better way or this is what it is ?

Comment: It's a completely different thing in react.

Comment: React is opposite. Using `addEventListener` is bad practice in React. Let React handle events. Use the `onClick` property. Otherwise React may not know about the event. Note that the `onClick` in React is not the same as DOM `onclick`. It is a synthetic event. React will handle it internally or dispatch it to the DOM as appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I think adding "onClick" event to an element is a bad practice

It isn't. Do not confuse JSX properties with HTML attributes.

---

Getting a reference to the element and then using `addEventListener` in React, on the other hand, **is** a bad practise as it bypasses React's methods for keeping its internal model in sync with the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do event handling in React. Also take a look at the official documentation. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

```
import React from 'react';
function App(){ 
  const doSomething = (e) => {
    console.log('event', e)
  }

  return(
    <div>
    <h1 onClick={doSomething}>Hello React</h1>
  </div>
  );

  
}
export default App;
```